# What is "plurarity"?

Tags: word-meaning

Reading this article, there is a line,

> Americans believe that President Biden faced bigger challenges than his predecessor Donald Trump during his first 100 days in office — and performed better than Trump despite those difficulties, according to a new Yahoo News/YouGov poll.

> The survey of 1,558 U.S. adults, which was conducted from April 27 to April 29, found that less than a third say Trump’s challenges were bigger than Biden’s (31 percent) or that Trump performed better (32 percent) during the first 100 days of his presidency. **Pluralities say** Biden has performed better than Trump (41 percent) in the face of greater obstacles (37 percent).

The definitions of plurarity from Merriam paid version.

> 1a: the state of being plural

> b: the state of being numerous

> c: a large number or quantity

> 2: pluralism 1  also : a benefice held by pluralism

> 3a: a number greater than another

> b: an excess of votes over those cast for an opposing candidate

> c: a number of votes cast for a candidate in a contest of more than two candidates that is greater than the number cast for any other candidate but not more than half the total votes cast

I presumably think possibly it would be 3a?

Please let me know here which defition the word "plurarity" falls into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definition 3a and 3c, but applied to a survey instead of an actual vote.

If, in a group of people, *more than half* vote for or otherwise approve of something, that is called a **majority**.

If no single candidate (or issue) receives more than half of the vote (or approval), the side with the *most* is called the **plurality**.

Here a plurality of people approve of Biden's performance—that is, more people than are either neutral or disapproving, but not 51% or more of the surveyed group.